# Excel replace all changing previous replacements

Tags: excel

I have a 370k row  file with 7 columns :

state/year/month/day/date/weekday/births

now the state column has the postal abbreviations for each state but i need to have the full name,but when i use find/replace all it changes previous and some other data.Is there an other way?

Comment: Use the *Match entire cell contents* option or in VBA, LookAt:=xlWhole. Limit the scope to the column with the state abbreviations.

Comment: @Jeeped thanks that helped!